# How to create a search index for a static Next.js site

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I wish to make part of my Next.js site searchable and am hoping to do this on the client side without calling the CMS (Storyblok) or using a 3rd part service such as Algolia.

There won't be a huge amount of results, so I was thinking it may be possible to create an index of the pages and their text content in a JSON file during export, and then querying this file for the search result data.

I haven't found any information about hooking into the build / export process, so am wondering if this is possible, or if perhaps there is an alternative solution that someone may be able to suggest.